# I messed up on the bootloader configuration of my Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10 disappeared

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bootloader, windows-10

I am new to Ubuntu. I got an HP Envy 14 notebook with Windows 10 preinstalled. After installing Ubuntu 14.04, my computer would still only boot Windows 10.

I was able to boot Ubuntu by using the Ubuntu install USB drive, but that wasn't permanent. Windows still automatically booted without the USB drive inserted. I used the terminal in Ubuntu, and I made some modifications so that Ubuntu now boots automatically, but now there's no choice to boot Windows.

I tried turning off legacy mode in UEFI, but it just caused a boot message that I don't have an OS installed. I tried to use Boot Repair, but it didn't work either.

How can I get a choice of OSes to boot from? Here is my [boot info summary](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23555427/).

Comment: You did not just make a few modifications. You erased Windows or reinstall Ubuntu to entire drive. If you have Windows data to try to recover STOP using drive. But you will not recover all files nor a bootable Windows. Best just to restore from your backup (you did make a backup?). If testdisk sees old partition deeper search may show files. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery Some that use Windows say the Windows repair/recovery tools may work better. Testdisk has photorec which just scans drive for anything that looks like a file.

Comment: I did not do an external backup. I have just used a separate recovery partition. Last time I tried to do some back ups for Windows 10 I have just recived errors. These were some reasons for me to switch to Linux environment.

Comment: If UEFI you may be able to reinstall Windows. Your product key is in UEFI, but you may need the vendor's version of Windows. But Microsoft did allow some generic installs, but you may have issues on drivers. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options When you erase all partitions you also erase the recovery partition.

Comment: If we go deeply to this topic, I am sure we would find a solution how to recover it, but I think it is not an issue for me anymore. I am happy with my new OS, and I have learned that Ubuntu's terminal is a powerful tool, so I am more cautious using it now. I had all my data backed upped (docs, music etc.) so I have just lost Win10. Thanks a lot for your attention to my problem! Take care